# Plots are too small with two minipages

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots, minipage

I have two plots, each one in a minipage, so they could be side by side. The left plot is significantly smaller than I would like it to be. How can I fix it?

```
\begin{frame}[t,fragile]{CI construction - example}
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
    height=1\linewidth, 
    width=1\linewidth,
    xlabel=$\hhest$,
    ylabel=$\Pr(\hhest)$,
    ticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize},
    label style = {font=\footnotesize},
    title style = {font=\footnotesize}, 
    title={$\hh=0.2$}, 
    ymin=0, 
    ymax=0.15, 
    ytick={0,0.05,0.1,0.15}, 
    yticklabels={0,0.05,0.1,0.15} 
        ]
    \addplot[name path=f, red] table[x=h2, y=0.200] {nfbc_h2_distribution.dat};
    \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:1,0);
    \addplot [
        thick,
        color=red,
        fill=red, 
        fill opacity=0.05
    ]
    fill between[
        of=f and axis,
        soft clip={domain=0:0.15},
    ];
    \addplot[mark=none, dash pattern=on 0.5pt off 0.5pt , black] coordinates {(0,0) (0, 0.15)};
    \addplot[mark=none, dash pattern=on 0.5pt off 0.5pt, black] coordinates {(0.15,0) (0.15, 0.15)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \\
    {\small $A_{0.2} = [0, 0.15]$}
    \end{center}
    \end{minipage}\hspace{0cm}%
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
    height=1\linewidth, 
    width=1\linewidth,
    xlabel=$\hhest$,
    ylabel=$\hh$,
    ticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize},
    label style = {font=\footnotesize},
    title style = {font=\footnotesize},
    xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1, ytick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,1}, yticklabels={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,1},
    ]
    \addplot[mark=none, red, thick] coordinates {(0,0.1) (0.15, 0.1)};  
    \addplot[mark=none, red, thick] coordinates {(0,0.2) (0.15, 0.2)};  
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}  
\end{frame}
```

I get:

[image: Page]

Comment: The minipages have different widths, but both axes are set have the width of the minipage, so some difference is surely to be expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really provide a MWE.

I have tried and it seems to me that if you set the axis' lengths to absolute value in `\begin{axis}`, you will get same sized plot areas:

```
\begin{axis}[height=4cm, width=4cm, %...
```